# How to open vim-like, manpage-like isolated display using python?

Tags: python, vim

When you open vim or manpage you can't scroll up and check your previous commands, you just stay in this isolated display.

How does this magic work? How to implement it with python?

Or at least say how this thingy is called so I google it properly.

Comment: I’d look for ansi escape codes

Comment: friend of mine suggested that this is called 'multiplexer' and i'm currently researching it

Comment: check this link: https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/master/pages/full_screen_apps.html

Comment: It's called [TUI, Text user interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface). See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+tui.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is called [The Alternate Screen Buffer](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-The-Alternate-Screen-Buffer). The terminal emulator provides two modes: *primary* and *alternate*; the latter has no scroll back, and when you switch between these buffers the contents in them is preserved. The `smcup` and `rmcup` [*ANSI Escape Sequences*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) are used for switching.

For example, the following displays a `FOOBAR` banner text for three seconds in the alternate buffer, then switches back to the primary one:

```
$ tput smcup; banner foobar; sleep 3s; tput rmcup
```

In Python, you could print the corresponding escape sequences on application start and exit; there may even be a library that does that for you.

Comment: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Terminal_control/Preserve_screen#Python - example with these codes